# Producing electricity from heat on a small scale?

Tags: power, solar-cell, thermal

Using a small solar panel like in the following picture we can produce around 0.935W of power with a peak voltage of 5.5V and current of 170mA under good sunny conditions [image]

Does a similar type of small device exist which we can turn heat into small amounts of power like in the above?

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/Thermoelectric-Fan-Driven-by-a-Candle/ more to be found https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1343&bih=633&site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=diy+thermoelectric+generator&revid=1462555393&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q1QIoAGoVChMIqO-muIOIxwIV1BiSCh1E-gSd some parts can be found in used 12v. coolers found a second hand stores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed there are devices like that. They are called thermoelectric generator.

The efficiency of those thermoelectric generators is quite low, in the order of 5-8%. So the needed temperature difference between the hot and cold side must be quite high to get a power in the order of your solar cell.

For example a device from TECTEG measures 40x40mm and you can get 0.66 W out of it (0.6V, 1.1A) at a temperature difference of 50K.

There are high temperature generators out there which you could attach, say to the exhaust pipe of a car to get a bigger temperature difference and much higher power levels (well still not impressive numbers but slightly better).

Answer (score 3):

Not heat per se, but temperature differences can be converted into electricity by thermoelectric devices via the [Seebeck effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Seebeck_effect). The proper harvesting chip can then be used to increase the voltage (which is usually in the tens or hundreds of millivolts) into something usable.

Comment: These are called Peltier devices usually https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Peltier_effect

Answer (score 1):

People have constructed small arrays of large numbers of thermocouples connected in series to generate small but useful amounts of power using various heat sources.

Small stirling engines have been used to generate electric power.

If you search using the terms "stirling engine" and "thermocouple," you will probably find some detailed information.